# Focus Windows when the mouse is over the window

Tags: arch-linux, window

I am using Arch Linux with the Gnome 3 GUI. I want to configure it like my Windows 7 Machine. So that everytime I open a new Window my mouse automatically is in that said Window and focuses it, when the mouse leaves the Window the focus is lost. Also the window should be moved into the foreground when it has focus. How can I achieve this? I already looked into the dconf-editor but couldnt find what I would need to solve this problem.

Is this possible? Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Gnome-tweaks handles this out-of-the-box - no additional extension is required:

- `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`
- start Gnome Tweaks → Windows tab → Focus on hover

Check out also, in the same tab, the slider "Raise Windows When Focused"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You need to install this extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/767/focus-follows-mouse/

The behavior you've mentioned is "focus follows mouse".